# Report cell content of specific column for multiple rows in R

Tags: r

I need to get R to output the "sample ID" of rows of my data frame (called "rats.df") containing missing values. I have so far been able to get the row numbers of the data frame containing missing values:

```
missing.val <- unique( unlist( lapply (rats.df, function (x) 
              which (is.na (x)))))
sort (missing.val, decreasing=FALSE)
```

Now I'm trying to output the value of the cell (in column 1 of the data frame) containing the sample ID of each of those rows, but the following commands just outputs all values in that column:

```
rats.df$sampleID [c(26,  38, 113, 127, 130, 152, 170, 176, 190, 232, 254, 257)]
```

I found this code on a different page, but because I don't understand all of it, I'm not able to apply it to my data frame. Well, I've tried, but somehow it doesn't give me the output I want:

```
index <- which(rats.df==113, arr.ind=TRUE)
paste(rownames(rats.df)[index[1]], colnames(rats.df)[index[1]], sep=", ")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do

```
rats.df[!complete.cases(rats.df), "sampleId"]
```

`complete.cases` will return TRUE for rows where there is no missing data.  So, negating that vector will give the indices of rows with missing data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems so simple, but because I'm a beginner I didn't think of negating the argument.

Comment: @KatrinPechinger please consider [accepting as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).